# R multiply multiple columns by constant if that row is for a group

Tags: r, dplyr

So I have some sports data and I need to multiply all of the 2020 data by 1.25 because the games were shorter than usual during the season but leave the other years' data as it is.

So if I have

| Season | Player | Kicks | Tackles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | A | 3 | 5 |
| 2019 | B | 1 | 2 |
| 2019 | C | 10 | 10 |
| 2020 | A | 2 | 4 |
| 2020 | B | 1 | 1 |
| 2020 | C | 8 | 8 |

What I want to do is multiply kicks and tackles by 1.25 if the Season is 2020

| Season | Player | Kicks | Tackles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | A | 3 | 5 |
| 2019 | B | 1 | 2 |
| 2019 | C | 10 | 10 |
| 2020 | A | 2.5 | 5 |
| 2020 | B | 1.25 | 1.25 |
| 2020 | C | 10 | 10 |

What is the best way to do this without having to send the 2020 data to it's own data frame and the appending it to the previous data after I multiply it?

I'm assuming there's a way to do it with mutate_if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
cols <- 3:4
#OR
#cols <- c('Kicks', 'Tackles')

df[cols] <- df[cols] + 0.25 * (df$Season == 2020) * df[cols]
df

#  Season Player Kicks Tackles
#1   2019  A      3.00    5.00
#2   2019  B      1.00    2.00
#3   2019  C     10.00   10.00
#4   2020  A      2.50    5.00
#5   2020  B      1.25    1.25
#6   2020  C     10.00   10.00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ifelse()` for this:

```r
df %>%
  mutate( Kicks = ifelse( Season == 2020, Kicks * 1.25, Kicks ),
          Tackles= ifelse( Season == 2020, Tackles* 1.25, Tackles))
```

It is not easy to use `mutate_if()` but if you have many columns you might use `mutate_at()`

```r
df %>%
  mutate_at( c("Kicks", "Tackles"), 
             ~ifelse(Season==2020, .x * 1.25, .x))
```